# nested preprocessor directives using backslash for joining lines

Tags: system-verilog

systemverilog allows lines to be concatenated with a trailing "\", and this is used very commonly with the tick ("`") preprocessor commands. So the following 2 sets of definitions are identical:

```
`define A(b) b + \
        5
`define A(b) b + 5
```

Similarly, in the following code, the definitions of X and P are expected to be identical. The only difference is that one version uses the "\" and the other version does not.

```
`define Y
`define X(a) `ifdef Y \
            `define Z a+2 \
            $display(`Z); \
        `endif
`define P(a) `ifdef Y `define R a+2 $display(`R); `endif

module m();
  initial begin
    `X(5) // expands as: $display(5+2);
    $display(`Z); // expands as: $display(5+2);
    `P(7) // expansion was empty, but no error reported
    $display(`R); // this reports an error: cyclical definition of R
  end
endmodule
```

But, as the comments mention, one of the versions does not work with the comercial simulators. So my question is: why is the second version wrong, and what exactly are the semantics of "\" for joining consecutive lines, especially in the context of using within `define and other preprocessor commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Anything** that is written after `define` is considered as *macro name* and **anything** after a space after macro name is considered as *macro value/text*. The optional formal arguments are delimited with braces as shown below.

> text_macro_definition ::= `define **text_macro_name macro_text**
>
> text_macro_name ::= text_macro_identifier [ **(** list_of_formal_arguments
>   **)** ]
>
> list_of_formal_arguments ::= formal_argument { **,** formal_argument }
>
> formal_argument ::= simple_identifier [ **=** default_text ]
>
> text_macro_identifier ::= identifier

Here, in order to compile successfully, you have to consider `define R a+2` as **one line** and `$display` as **another line**. The simulator will not understand by itself that when to end the define macro value and when to start another `$display` line.

It gets expanded as an assignment and display in a single line:

```
// Actual expansion
<macro> R = a+2 $display(R);
// Intended expansion
<macro> R = a+2 // assign value to R
$display(R); // then display R
```

> If more than one
>   line is necessary to specify the text, the newline shall be preceded by a backslash ( \ ).

The issue in this code is that **there is no delimiter for the** `define` **of** `R`. So `R` is getting defined as full `a+2 $display(R)`. Now if we add a `\`, then **the simulator understands that it is a new line** and hence it considers `$display` as next statement in compiling.

```
`define P(a) `ifdef Y `define R a+2 \
$display(`R); `endif
```

Refer to [IEEE 1800-2012 Sntax 22-2](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) for more information.